# How to change the CSS of a targeted div

Tags: css, reactjs

I am creating an interactive rating card with react. I have 5 divs which represent the number you are rating. When I click on one number I want to change the background of the targeted div to white.

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState('blue');
  const changeColor = () => {
    setColor('white');
  };

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="container">
        <p class="question">How did we do?</p>
        <p>
          Please let us know how we did with your support request. All feedback
          is appreciated to help us improve our offering!
        </p>
        <div id="numbers">
          <div
            className="circle"
            onClick={setColor}
            style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
          >
            1
          </div>
          <div
            className="circle"
            onClick={changeColor}
            style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
          >
            2
          </div>
          <div className="circle">3</div>
          <div className="circle">4</div>
          <div className="circle">5</div>
        </div>
        <button className="btn"> Submit </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So far I tried to work with an `useState` hook. I read in some other sources to use the `e.target.value` or to give every div a special key value. I tried it with both but didn't manage to solve it. At the moment div 1 and div 2 change the color if I click on one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const App = () => {
    const [selectedStar, setSelectedStar] = React.useState();

    return (
        <div>
          <div
            className={`circle ${selectedStar === 1 && "active"}`}
            onClick={() => setSelectedStar(1)}
          >
            1
          </div>
          <div
            className={`circle ${selectedStar === 2 && "active"}`}
            onClick={() => setSelectedStar(2)}
          >
            2
          </div>
          <div
            className={`circle ${selectedStar === 3 && "active"}`}
            onClick={() => setSelectedStar(3)}
          >
            3
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.circle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle.active {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```